# Is there any downside in obtaining a US re-entry permit (via I131 Application for Travel Document) if eventually one doesn't stay outside the US much?

Tags: usa, citizenship, residency

Is there any downside in obtaining a US re-entry permit (via [Form I-131, Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/i-131) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823021419/https://www.uscis.gov/i-131))) if eventually one doesn't stay outside the United States much? The potential applicant for the US re-entry permit is a US lawful permanent resident who might apply for US naturalization (N-400) in two years.